# Weird behaviour of DropDownList Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

Weird behaviour happening in my `DropDownList` Asp.net

**My Code:**

```
                 <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLFromMinutes" runat="server" Width="20%">
                                <asp:ListItem Text="00" Value="00"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="15" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="30" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Text="45" Value="45"></asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
```

However when i run it for example if 15 is the Selected Value i get it Twice in my `DropDownList`

While Debugging in FireBug get the following:

```
<select id="ContentPlaceHolder1_DDLFromMinutes" style="width:20%;" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$DDLFromMinutes">
<option value="00" selected="selected">30</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
</select>
```

Code behind:

```
string Frominput = seprateFromTime[1];
                string Frommin = Frominput.Substring(0, 2);
                DDLFromMinutes.SelectedItem.Text = Frommin;
                if (DDLFromMinutes.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    DDLFromMinutes.SelectedIndex = DDLFromMinutes.Items.IndexOf(DDLFromMinutes.Items.FindByText(Frommin));
                }
```

[image]

While saving the Data is use `DDLFromMinutes.SelectedItem.Text` Could this be an issue?

Comment: Show us your code-behind that sets the selected item please.

Comment: There is no code behind for the selection The User just selects and saves the Data

Comment: Sorry vini, I think you need to reformat your question, because we can't understand it.

Comment: ok i am reformatting it

Comment: Have added my code behind

Comment: Lets say you selected 15, is it appearing twice (like 15 two times in ddl) ?

Comment: It works fine now MyDropDown.SelectedValue just did this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use MyDropDown.SelectedValue instead of selectedItem.Text.

Details here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

do you want to get the value of drop down list? If so, I think you need to change SelectedItem to SeletedValue.